# How to check the convergence of the series whose elements are taken from the set $A$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $A$ be the set $\lbrace n\in \mathbb{N} : n=1$ or the only prime factors of $n$ are $2$ or $3 \rbrace $. So, $6\in A$ but $10\notin A$. Let $S=\sum_{n\in A} \frac{1}{n} $.

What can be said about $S$ ? Can $S$ be real number or $\infty$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:   compare $\;S\;$ to $\;\displaystyle\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\,\frac{1}{2^j}\right)\,\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\,\frac{1}{3^k}\right)\,$.

Comment: Does the order matters while summing?

Comment: @Unknownx Not for series with all positive terms, since they are [absolutely convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence).

Answer (score 2):

This is
$$\sum_{j,k=0}^\infty\frac1{2^j3^k}
=\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac1{2^j}\right)
\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{3^k}\right).$$
It should be possible to evaluate this explicitly.