# Can I prove the divergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ using this technique?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, soft-question

When I see the answer to the problem.
[How to check the convergence of the series whose elements are taken from the set $A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338970/how-to-check-the-convergence-of-the-series-whose-elements-are-taken-from-the-set)

One question raised in my mind, Can I prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges using the following technique?

By the Prime decomposition theorem, $n=2^{j_1}3^{j_2}...$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{j_1=1,j_2=0,...}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{j_1}3^{j_2}...}=\sum_{j_1=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{j_1}}\sum_{j_2=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{j_2}}...=\frac{2}{1}.\frac{3}{2}.\frac{5}{4}...$$

Can I judge using the above technique? Where did I go wrong?. Please help me.

Comment: The idea is fine as exposed [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/AfterEuler.shtml) (actually this is a way of proving infinitude of primes !).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I really wonder, How could I think like this.!!!. thank you for the reference.

Comment: [This](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/HEDI-2006-03.pdf) might also be of interest, same idea but in my opinion a little further explained.

Comment: You still have to prove that the product $\prod \left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)$ took over primes is divergent, which is quite the same as proving that $\sum \frac{1}{p}$ is divergent. True, but non-trivial at all.

Comment: Theorem: If $a_n\geq 0$ then $\sum_na_n$ converges iff $\prod_n(1+a_n)$ converges. See the above comment by Jack D"Aurizio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting remark is that due to Euler's product

$$ \forall s>1,\qquad \zeta(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}=\prod_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1} $$

we are allowed to state:

> Since the harmonic series is divergent, there are infinite primes.

Of course you may also state

> Since there are infinite primes and their sequence does not grow too fast, the harmonic series is divergent

and prove through elementary means that $\pi(n)\geq \frac{n\log 2}{2\log n}$, but this is [*nuking mosquitoes*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798215/nuking-the-mosquito-ridiculously-complicated-ways-to-achieve-very-simple-resul).
The previous claim can also be stated as

> Since $\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\frac{1}{p}$ is divergent, $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent as well.